# Sending JSON to Rails

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, json

My issue is that the escape character is invalidating my JSON. I am sending my JSON to a Rails sever but when it arrives it gains some escape characters.

Is there something I can do to Solve this on my restfull class or is it something to be corrected on the server side?

Here is the JSON I'm sending,

```
[session={"password":"********","email":"********@omobile.com.br"}]
```

And here is the JSON thats appearing on the servers log:

```
{"session"=>"{\"password\":\"********\",\"email\":\"********@omobile.com.br\"}"}
```

I've tried these different ways to send my JSON and the result is the same:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.accumulate("email", username);
object.accumulate("password", password);
String jsonString = object.toString();

Session session = new Session();
session.setEmail(username);
session.setPassword(password);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(session, Session.class);
```

Comment: Could you post your code to send the JSON string from the Android app?

Comment: thanks man I've tryed these both ways and the result is still the same

Comment: And don't post your private information such as password and email address. Use `********` instead.

Comment: it was a random password and email but i've chnaged it anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is a mess, because neither of the strings you posted is actually JSON. The first one actually I don't know what it is, while the second one likely means that on the Ruby side you have this Ruby hash, in which the key "session" refers to a JSON-encoded hash.

We can't tell what's going on the wire because you didn't post the code, so we can't tell if your server expects a form-encoded request body, a multipart one, or directly a JSON-encoded object.

I want you to consider that the only JSON I see is the portion:

```
{"password": "********","email":"********@omobile.com.br"}
```

As I said, this can be passed as-is, or as a part in a mulipart envelope, or even url-encoded. The format is really estabilished on the server. For example I made a quick test using Apache HttpClient:

```
public class GsonSendToSinatra {

    private static class Session {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String username, password;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Session session = new Session();
        session.username = "foo@example.com";
        session.password = "qwerty1234";

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String responseText = Request.Post("http://localhost:4567/echo")
            .bodyString(gson.toJson(session), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .execute()
            .returnContent()
            .asString();

        System.out.println(responseText);
    }
}
```

and Sinatra on the server:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

post '/echo' do
  content_type "text/plain"
  layout false

  session = JSON.parse request.body.read

  session.map {|k,v| "#{k}: #{v}\n"}
end
```

I hope this example helps you to figure out what are the moving parts in a HTTP dialogue and how you can combine them.

Comment: I've used the same String and approach to comunicate with j2EE servers using the JSON and Gson Frameworks and I has always worked this is the first time I'm having this problem

Comment: Everything works when client and server both agree on the same protocol ;) if you showed us your client and your server...

Comment: @Raffaele *"...because Jon Skeet doesn't achieve badges, badges achieve Jon Skeet"*  :-D

Comment: @LaiVung Shamelessly stolen from someone on twitter... :P

Comment: @Raffaele i will see with my server developer to correct this issue thanks for the explanation